# Infinite loop while login

Tags: facebook, email, loops, authentication, authorization

Some of our users are stuck in infinite loop while login.
A user already gave authorization for email. Our app wants to access the mail but cannot access. It redirects user to authorization page. But Facebook sends him back to app because it knows the auth is already given.

This has started one day ago and only some of our users are affected..

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Can you post the login code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();


if ($user_id) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    print_r($user_profile);
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e."brr".$user_id);
    $user_id = null;



  }
}


if(!$user_id||!$user_profile['email']){

$auth_url="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".$appid."&redirect_uri=".$canvasurl.$reflek."&scope=email"; //&scope=email,read_stream

echo "<script> top.location.href='" .$auth_url . "'</script>";
die();

}
```